# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars varsIgnorePattern

Tags: eslint

I have such code, and a lot of files have the same declared class
when I set '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars' rule eslint underline MyClass and show warn 'MyClass is defined but never used'.

```
export default class MyClass .... {}
```

This rule works fine when declare like below

```
class MyClass .... {}
export default MyClass
```

I add to the rule "varsIgnorePattern": "MyClass" and rule doesn't show warn for first example.
I wrote regex expression `(?<=export default class\s)\w+` but rule underline MyClass again.

Comment: Only the variable name is matched against the pattern, not arbirary text around.

Comment: The checker complaint is legit: the name is never used. You can do `export default class {}` without having to call it somehow. However, I agree that it may be very useful for readability - consider reporting this as a feature request to maintainers (both for functions and classes)

Comment: it makes sense. I'll write in issue on github